# Razor Views and Javascript : Append to multiSelect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, multi-select

I am trying to append options to multiSelect. But the data is not reflected on UI.
However, I can see the change in DOM through chrome dev tools.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductAndServices,
 Model.ProductsAndServices.Select(item => new SelectListItem
 {
     Value = item.Key.ToString(),
     Text = item.Value,
     Selected = item.Key == Model.ProductId,
 }), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control input-fields-normal dropdown-ie multiSelect", @id = "productAndServicesDDL", @multiple = "multiple", @placeHolder = "Select Products and Services", style = "width:300px; height:300px;" })


  $(function () {
       $('#productAndServicesDDL').change(function () {
       
       }).multipleSelect({
           width: '100%'
       });
   });
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
var option = $('<option></option>')
    .attr('value', 199)
    .text('Any Service XYZ')
    .prop('selected', true);
```

Trying to append the options

```
$('#productAndServicesDDL').append(option).change()
```

When I try to use the following, the multiSelect element gets allignment issues

```
$('#productAndServicesDDL').multiselect('refresh');
```

Comment: What's `multipleSelect()`?  (or `.multiselect()` as you have it later)  You have a 3rd-party front-end wrapper over your `<select>` - remove that line to see what's happening to the `select` itself, then read the documentation to determine how to refresh (which looks like the last line is an attempt).  Let us know what the wrapper is (eg a github page or CDN link)